# What was the orange gap which lies between padding-bottom and border-bottom?

Tags: html, css

I found that there was a very slightly orange gap between padding-bottom and border-bottom. What was it?

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
  width: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>introduce</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did u mean the whitespace on the body ? if yes try to set this css will resolve the problem "body { margin:0; }"

Comment: Sorry in your snippet I don't see any slight gap between `padding-bottom` and `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gap" IS your border-bottom.
Theres the div height, padding, and border.

[image]